Возможно ли в Hilt запровайдить два класса с разным Component, если один принимает в конструктор другой?
Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли в хилте запровайдить два класса с разным Component, если один из этих классов принимает в конструктор другой? Если нельзя, то я столкнулся с проблемой, когда одна зависимость тянет другую, и тогда придется кучу модулей поменять с ViewModelComponent на SingletonComponent.
Один модуль провайдит синглтоны, потому что обработка диплинков не привязана к ЖЦ какого-либо класса:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DeeplinkModule {

    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun provideDeeplinkProcessor (сardReissueRepository: CardReissueRepository): DeeplinkProcessorV2 = MyDeeplinkProcessor(сardReissueRepository) 
}

Другой модуль провайдит объекты для вьюмодели, поэтому я выставил ViewModelComponent:
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ViewModelModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideCardReissueRepository (/* Много зависимостей */): CardReissueRepository = CardReissueRepositoryImpl(/* Много зависимостей */)
}

CardReissueRepository принимает в конструктор много всего, и если делать его SingletonComponent, то все его зависимости тоже придётся делать SingletonComponent. Или нет?

Ваши provide методы можно заменить на @Bind и @Inject constructor и не махаться с ручным прокидыванием зависимостей в модуле. С вашей реализацией (почти) весь смысл даггера пропадает

Прошу прощения, нашел опечатку. Там репозиторий с интерфейсом, так что @Inject constructor не получится

Почему не получится, @Inject constructor нужно на реализацию добавлять (impl),  а не интерфейс, и связывать реализацию с интерфейсом с помощью @Binds метода в модуле, вместо @Provides

Можно, если scope (component) имеет больший ЖЦ, чем объект куда он инжектится. SingletonComponent имеет больший ЖЦ, чем ViewModelComponent, соответственно SingletonComponent объекты можно инжектить в ViewModelComponent объекты, а наоборот нельзя

А если есть репозиторий-синглтон, который хранит стейт, и юзкейс, который обращается к этому репозиторию и используется только в какой-то одной вьюмодели. Как тогда их провайдить? Ведь репозиторий будет синглтоном (т.к. хранит стейт), а юзкейс по идее должен жить столько же, сколько вьюмодель, значит надо юзать ViewModelComponent. Но так не получится. Как решить такую проблему?

Что значит не получится? Если репозиторий singleton, то его можно заинжектить куда угодно, тк у него самый большой ЖЦ

Если есть какая-то ошибка, то добавляйте ошибку в вопрос
